# Improve switch statement in PHP or suggest an alternative workaround

Tags: php, wordpress, switch-statement

I am trying to improve the below switch statement. What's happening here is that the code is called multiple times based on an x amount of tokens found, so the below code runs once per token.

If the `$post->ID` is not found then a notification is sent to that token and the id gets added in the database.

This works however at some point it's stopping after around 40% of tokens checked presumably because the ID is found? Since I am on wordpress, I used the `update_option` to store the id in a table but perhaps an alternative approach can be used?

```
$os = $this->os;
switch ($os) {

    case "iOS":
        $iOS_pastPushSavedID = get_option( 'iOS_pastPushSavedID',  $default = false);
        if($post->ID != $iOS_pastPushSavedID) {
            update_option( 'iOS_pastPushSavedID', $post->ID, no);
            $sendPush = true;
            //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $iOS_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);   
        } else {
            //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $iOS_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID); 
            $sendPush = false;
        }
    break;

    case "Android":
        $android_pastPushSavedID = get_option( 'android_pastPushSavedID',  $default = false);
        if($post->ID != $android_pastPushSavedID) {
            //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $android_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            update_option( 'android_pastPushSavedID', $post->ID, no);
            $sendPush = true;           
        } else {
            //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $android_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            $sendPush = false;
        }
    break;

    case "Fire OS":
        $fireos_pastPushSavedID = get_option( 'fireos_pastPushSavedID',  $default = false);
        if($post->ID != $fireos_pastPushSavedID) {
            //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $fireos_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            update_option( 'fireos_pastPushSavedID', $post->ID, no);
            $sendPush = true;           
        } else {
            //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $fireos_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            $sendPush = false;
        }
    break;

    case "Safari":
        $safari_pastPushSavedID = get_option( 'safari_pastPushSavedID',  $default = false);
        if($post->ID != $safari_pastPushSavedID) {
            //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $safari_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            update_option( 'safari_pastPushSavedID', $post->ID, no);
            $sendPush = true;

        } else {
            //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $safari_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            $sendPush = false;
        }
    break;

    case "Chrome":
        $chrome_pastPushSavedID = get_option( 'chrome_pastPushSavedID',  $default = false);
        if($post->ID != $chrome_pastPushSavedID) {
            //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $chrome_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            update_option( 'chrome_pastPushSavedID', $post->ID, no);
            $sendPush = true;           
        } else {
            //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $chrome_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            $sendPush = false;
        }
    break;

    case "Firefox":
        $firefox_pastPushSavedID = get_option( 'firefox_pastPushSavedID',  $default = false);
        if($post->ID != $firefox_pastPushSavedID) {
            //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $firefox_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            update_option( 'firefox_pastPushSavedID', $post->ID, no);
            $sendPush = true;

        } else {
        //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $firefox_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
            $sendPush = false;
        }
    break;

    default:
        $sendPush = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your process, this is a very DRY / concise way to do it without the verbose `switch/case` block:

```
$os_opts=[
    'iOS'=>'iOS',
    'Android'=>'android',
    'Fire OS'=>'fireos',
    'Safari'=>'safari',
    'Chrome'=>'chrome',
    'Firefox'=>'firefox'
];

$os=$this->os;
$sendPush=false;
if(isset($os_opts[$os])){                           // deny empty and invalid options
    $os_opt="{$os_opts[$os]}_pastPushSavedID";     // build string for next two functions
    if($post->ID!=get_option($os_opt,$default=false)){
        update_option($os_opt,$post->ID,no);
        $sendPush = true;
    }
}
```

The `$os_opts` array has keys that match `$os`, and values that work with `get_option()` & `update_option()`.  This will largely reduce code length, and make future modifications very easy to do.

Since the `get_option()` result is only used once, it doesn't make sense to declare it as a variable; just use it in the if condition.

The first parameter of `get_option()` and `update_option()` always end with the same substring.  I makes sense to prepend the `$os_opts[$os]` value to it and declare it as a variable.  The variable declaration is not *necessary* but my personal rule is; if you are going to use data more than once use a variable, if only once don't declare it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. You can shorten your code like this.

```
$optionName='';//added some default values
$sendPush = false;;//added some default values
switch ($os) {

    case "iOS":
        $optionName='iOS_pastPushSavedID';
    break;

    case "Android":
        $optionName='android_pastPushSavedID';
    break;

    case "Fire OS":
        $optionName='fireos_pastPushSavedID';
    break;

    case "Safari":
        $optionName='safari_pastPushSavedID';
    break;

    case "Chrome":
        $optionName='chrome_pastPushSavedID';
    break;

    case "Firefox":
        $optionName='firefox_pastPushSavedID';
    break;

    default:
        $sendPush = false;
}
//this is operation which is common when $optionName is not empty.
if(!empty($optionName))
{
    $optionData = get_option($optionName,  $default = false);
    if($post->ID != $optionData) {
        update_option( $optionData, $post->ID, no);
        $sendPush = true;
    } else {
        $sendPush = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Will check it out and revert. Thanks for the fast reply. Would you suggest a faster alternative from storing the var in MySQL Wordpress? or my solution ok you think? Tx

Comment: @Jason welcome... I think its okay this is the shortest code for the thing which you are trying to do here. I my code i gave you a way from which you can prevent yourself rewriting same code again and again .. :)

Comment: Thanks! Will try this tomorrow and will let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Id write it more like this

```
function getOptionSpecifier() {

    switch ($this->os) {
        case "iOS":
            return 'iOS_pastPushSavedID';
        case "Android":
            return 'android_pastPushSavedID';
        case "Android":
            return 'android_pastPushSavedID';
        case "Fire OS":
            return 'fireos_pastPushSavedID';
        case "Safari":
            return 'safari_pastPushSavedID';
        case "Chrome":
            return 'chrome_pastPushSavedID';
        case "Firefox":
            return 'firefox_pastPushSavedID';
        default:
            return '';

    }
}

function send_notification($id) {
    $optionSpecifier = getOptionSpecifier();

    if ($optionSpecifier === NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    $pastPushSavedID = get_option( $optionSpecifier,  $default = false);

    if($id != $pastPushSavedID) {
        update_option( $optionSpecifier, $id, no);
        return true;
        //$title = ($os . '_New Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $iOS_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
    } else {
        //$title = ($os . '_Duplicate Push = ' . ' storedID: ' . $iOS_pastPushSavedID . ' / postID: ' . $post->ID);
        return false;
    }
}

$sendPush  = send_notification($post->ID);
```

Multiple functions ala "separation of concerns" and so ...